# Access container's parent view from custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a custom class `myCustomClass`, that is a `subclass` of `UIView`. I will be adding a `UITextField` as a `subview`. Then, in the `storyboard`, I set a `UIView's` class to the custom class.

In the storyboard, I have a `viewController` with a `containerView`. The `containerView` is connected to a `UITalbeViewController`. The `UIView` (that I set it's class to `myCustomClass`), is located in the `tableViewController`.

How can I add the `textField` as a `subview` of the `viewController`? (I know this is a bit complicating, so if you have any questions, please ask in the comments.)

**Edit**

Here's what I want. When you want to add a `subview` to the `parentView`, you would do the following:

```
[self.parentViewController.view addSubview:mySubview];
```

What I want to know is if there's a way to do that in a custom class file.

Comment: You don't add subviews to a viewController.  You add subview's to the viewController's view.  i.e. [viewController.view addSubview]

Comment: All together, I have 3 classes. 1 - myCustomClass. 2 - UITableViewControllerClass. 3 - UIViewContoller.    UITableViewControllerClass is the embedded vc. I'm trying to add a view from myCustomClass, to UIVIewController's view.

Comment: Here is a test project I'm working on http://jmp.sh/3XkLhUm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your custom class is a subclass of UIView, it can do everything that a regular UIView can do.

Comment: The way I would add a subview to a parentVC would be like this: self.parentViewControlller.view addsubview:. But I'm trying to do that from a custom class.